# Getting lines one by one to the dynamically allocated char array

Tags: c

Is this possible to get lines from file one by one and save them to the char array which size is determined by the number of characters in each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from
https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

getline automatically allocates lineptr if it is NULL or not large enough to contain the string

Comment: I tried this function but didn't quite get it how to use it properly. Could You please give me the example of usage?

Comment: http://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=1112 instead of stdin you would put your filestream

Comment: I mean I see the example in the link you shown below, but how do I declare the array then? Can I somehow cast the ssize_t to use it for creating the array?

Comment: By char array do you mean a string, or do you you want to store an array of strings?

Comment: I mean a string containing the whole line.

Comment: the string containing the whole line gets stored in lineptr

Comment: Ah, ofc. Sry, I'm a total beginner in that. Also, my English is not so good so I don't understand everything. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your question:

*Is this possible to get lines from file one by one and save them to the char array which size is determined by the number of characters in each line?*

The answer:

`Yes`

To actually accomplish this, suggest looking at the functions: `fgets()`  and `getline()`.  Both are found in the header file: `stdio.h`.   Read their associated MAN pages for details.